# Checking if elements are already in a Java array

Tags: java, arrays

The project I am working on right now involves me reading words from a text file and loading them into an array (and eventually a binary tree, but that will be finished later). I must load both the word and the word's frequency (initially 1) into the array, so I have packed both variables into an object `WordNode`. I am able to load the words into the array, but things fall apart when I try to check if a word is already in the array. If it is, I must increase the frequency by 1. However, my code does not even check the word and simply adds it anyway (I presume it's checking the reference to the variable and not the word itself). Below is my `main` method and the `WordNode` class.

Main method:

```
public class Driver {
/////////////// fields ///////////////
public static ArrayUnorderedList<WordNode> wordArray = new ArrayUnorderedList<WordNode>();
public static LinkedBinarySearchTree<WordNode> wordTree = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<WordNode>();   //tree to hold words

/////////////// methods ///////////////
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //ask for filename       
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to read from: ");
    Reader file = new FileReader(reader.readLine());

    //read file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    while(input.hasNext()) {
        //get words from file
        String word = input.next();

        //remove non-word characters and convert to lowercase
        word = word.replaceAll("\\W", "");
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        //create node
        WordNode newWord = new WordNode(word);

        //if word is already in array
        if(wordArray.contains(newWord)) {
            System.out.println("Word is already in array");

            //increment frequency by 1
            int index = wordArray.find(newWord);
            wordArray.list[index].setFrequency(wordArray.list[index].getFrequency() + 1);
            System.out.println(newWord.getWord() + newWord.getFrequency());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Word is not yet in array");

            //add word to tree
            System.out.println(newWord.getWord());
            wordArray.addToRear(newWord);
        }
    }

    //insert into tree

    //perform traversals on tree
}
```

WordNode class:

```
public class WordNode {
   protected String word;
   protected WordNode left, right;
   protected int frequency;

   /**
    * Creates a new node with the specified data.
    * @param obj the element that will become a part of the new node
    */
   WordNode(String obj) {
      word = obj;
      left = null;
      right = null;
      frequency = 1;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the word.
    * @return the word
    */
   public String getWord() {
      return word;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the word.
    * @param word the word to set
    */
   public void setWord(String word) {
      this.word = word;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the left.
    * @return the left
    */
   public WordNode getLeft() {
      return left;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the left.
    * @param left the left to set
    */
   public void setLeft(WordNode left) {
      this.left = left;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the right.
    * @return the right
    */
   public WordNode getRight() {
      return right;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the right.
    * @param right the right to set
    */
   public void setRight(WordNode right) {
      this.right = right;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the frequency.
    * @return the frequency
    */
   public int getFrequency() {
      return frequency;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the frequency.
    * @param frequency the frequency to set
    */
   public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
      this.frequency = frequency;
   }
}
```

Some methods from the ArrayList class:

```
/**
* Returns true if this list contains the specified element.
* @param target the element that the list is searched for
* @return true if the target is in the list, false if otherwise 
*/
public boolean contains(T target) {
    return (find(target) != NOT_FOUND);
}

/**
* Returns the array index of the specified element, or the
* constant NOT_FOUND if it is not found.
* @param target the element that the list will be searched for
* @return the integer index into the array containing the target element, or the NOT_FOUND constant
*/
public int find(T target) {
    int scan = 0, result = NOT_FOUND;
    boolean found = false;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
       while (!found && scan < rear) {
          if (target.equals(list[scan])) {
              found = true;
          } else {
             scan++;
          }
       }
    }

    if (found) {
       result = scan;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate reason your code doesn't work is that `ArrayUnorderedList#contains()` probably relies on the `equals()` method to determine if the entry is in the list. Without seeing the definition of the class it's impossible to know.

Since you haven't provided an override of `equals()`, it's using object identity (the default from `Object`) so every `WordNode` is distinct from every other `WordNode`.

If you want to use `ArrayUnorderedList` then you must implement `WordNode#equals()` with the correct behavior.

However, you should consider using a `Map<String,Integer>` (or `Map<String,WordNode>`) instead to store the frequencies.  This will be much faster.

Comment: That's what I thought (each object was different and so the words weren't being compared), but I wasn't sure how to make it so just the words would be compared, and the relevant objects could be altered. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement `WordNode#equals()` since our class never talked about that. I also do not know what a map is, though I don't doubt it would be much easier.

Comment: Rather - I do know how to implement an equals method, but should I compare words or some other value? Also, when I override the method, do I call that instead of `contains()`? Or can I make `contains()` use my new method?

Comment: The point of `equals()` is to compare whatever is important for your particular class.  In this case, it could just return the result of `String#equals()` on the words themselves.  Oh, and you should also implement `hashCode()` as well, in this case return the hash code of the `WordNode.word`.

Comment: Alright, I will try that. Instead of using `contains()`, I should now use the `equals()` method I wrote in its place? Also, our class has not learned what `hashCode()` is, so I don't think I can use that.

Comment: No, `contains()` is the method on `ArrayUnorderedList` that will _use_ your override of `equals()` to determine if the list contains that word already.  You provide the `equals()` method (as an override of `Object#equals()`.  By definition, any other class that needs to compare two instances of your class will invoke `Object#equals(...)`, which will get dispatched to _your_ equals method and will return true or false for _your_ objects.

Comment: Ah, I think I see... so I put the new `equals()` method in `WordNode` and that method will automatically be used? That makes sense! I thought I had to somehow connect it to `ArrayUnorderedList`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help! However, I've included a new `equals()` method (based on the one found below) and am now getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LWordNode;`. What might be happening here?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override eqauls in your WordNode:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if(o instanceof WordNode) {
        WordNode temp = (WordNode) o;
        return(temp.getWord().equals(this.word));
     }
     else
         System.out.println("Object o you passed is not a WordNode");
}
```

This way if two different WordNode object has the same String as word field they are considered equals

how to call the equals:

```
WordNode n1 = new WordNode();
n1.setWord("test");

WordNode n2 = new WordNode();
n2.setWord("test");

System.out.println(n1.equals(n2));
```

So the equals receives an object of type Object but when you call the equals on a WordNode you havo to provide an object which is instance of WordNode too otherwise the cast i made fails (your exception) and of course it makes no sense to verify if an Object is equal to a WordNode

Comment: I have implemented your code, but I am now running into an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LWordNode;`. Why might this be?

Comment: The way I have implemented this code is so that the method overrides the usual `equals()` method for `contains()` as discussed above. How could it not be operating on two `WordNode` objects? I don't really understand where the cast error is coming from, since I thought the method already took two `WordNode` objects (the one passed to the method, and `this`). For reference, I included the method in the `WordNode` class.

Comment: Please see my new edit. I use instance of to check if the object yuo pass as parameter in the equals is really a WordNode instance. Also please provide updated code where you call the equals.